# Android first app error in event log

Tags: android, android-studio

hope I find someone that would help me with my first android application, I have just created a new project, at first I'm getting the below errors in the event log:

```
5:06:35 PM Gradle sync started
5:06:35 PM Gradle sync failed: Invalid Project Jdk
5:06:35 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:07:14 PM Gradle sync started
5:07:15 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:07:25 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:07:35 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:07:45 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:07:56 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:08:01 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:08:06 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:08:11 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:08:16 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:15:58 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:16:03 PM AssertionError: update failed for ActionGroup:  (The virtual device to render the layout with)[]: Already disposed: Module: 'MobileSupport'
5:16:08 PM com.intellij.diagnostic.MessagePool$TooManyErrorsException: Too many IDE fatal errors. Monitoring stopped.
```

I haven't done anything yet, and also not showing the mobile phone that should render my work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please in android-studio try:

1. Build >> Clean project
2. Restart android-studio

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like the Android studio is not able to locate the folder
   where your JDK is located. If you have already downloaded the JDK,
   go to

   File -> Project Structure -> SDK location tab -> in JDK location
   text box

   Provide it the correct path to where you have extracted your JDK
   folder.
2. Another possibility is that, your SDK path may contain whitespace
               characters, to fix that, go to

   File -> Project Structure -> SDK location tab -> Android SDK
   Location Text Box

   Make sure the SDK path doesn't contain whitespace
               for example: `C:\Program Files\Android\sdk` Program Files folder
               here contains a space, so move the SDK to another folder which has
               no spaces and provide that path here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the ".idea" folder